# Using DotNet framework to create Excel files in Dynamics AX

Tags: .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I want to create an Excel file in batch job, I tried to use SysExcelApplication class but it doesn't work in batch job, I also had problems with winAPIServer::fileExist/::FileDelete class, i found solution by using System.IO.file::exist/Delete(filename)
Here's my code in X++:

```
SysExcelApplication   xlsapplication;
;
xlsApplication = SysExcelApplication::construct();

xlsWorkBookCollection    = xlsApplication.workbooks();
xlsWorkBook              = xlsWorkBookCollection.add();
xlsWorkSheetCollection   = xlsWorkBook.worksheets();
xlsWorkSheet             = xlsWorkSheetCollection.itemFromNum(1);
```

I got an error on SysExcelApplication::construct(); when running batch job(can execute on server side), how can I do the same with dotnet?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options that you have:

- You can use XML and XSLT to do it. I have put an article on my blog once
  that simply takes a simple XML and transforms it to fit into a saved Excel file (in XML format) This can be a good solution since writing XML files from Dynamics Ax is quite easy. The article shows how to create an XML with items and shows how to get it into Excel. [Using C#, XML and XSLT to create an Excel spreadsheet](http://www.ksaelen.be/wordpresses/dynamicsaxblog/2009/08/using-c-xml-xslt-to-create-excel-spreadsheet/)
- You could use OpenXML ([Using C# and OpenXML SDK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97307/Using-C-and-Open-XML-SDK-2-0-for-Microsoft-Office))
- And there is also an option to use third party controls created to do
  this ([Infragistics Excel](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/infragistics-excel/) for example)